# If $ \theta + \phi + \psi = \frac{\pi}{2} $, show that $ \sin^2\theta+\sin^2\phi+\sin^2\psi+2\sin\theta\sin\phi\sin\psi=1 $

Tags: trigonometry

If $ \theta + \phi + \psi = \frac{\pi}{2} $, show that

$$ \sin^2\theta+\sin^2\phi+\sin^2\psi+2\sin\theta\sin\phi\sin\psi=1 $$

I need some help on how to start this question. I've tried everything but haven't been able to make progress. I just finished solving hundreds of trig questions in my textbook, but can't solve this more difficult question found on an exam paper.

Comment: Hint: $\psi = \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta - \phi$

Comment: You should include whatever you have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know a well known identity that if $A+B+C=\pi$ then

$\cos A + \cos B + \cos C= 1+4\sin \frac{A}{2} \sin \frac{B}{2} \sin \frac{C}{2}$

Plug in $A=2\theta$ , $B=2\phi$ , $C=2\psi$

$\cos 2\theta + \cos 2\phi + \cos2\psi= 1+4\sin \theta \sin \phi \sin \psi$

$1-2\sin ^2\theta+1-2\sin ^2\phi+1-2\sin ^2\psi= 1+4\sin \theta \sin \phi \sin \psi$

$2\sin ^2\theta+2\sin ^2\phi+2\sin ^2\psi+4\sin \theta \sin \phi \sin \psi=2$

therefore, we have

$\sin ^2\theta+\sin ^2\phi+\sin ^2\psi+2\sin \theta \sin \phi \sin \psi=1$